# Serenity BDD reports naming

Tags: junit, report, regression-testing, serenity-bdd

I am using the Serenity BDD tool Version 1.2.1-rc.6 with JUnit 4.12 to automate some regression testing. The project is working fine so far but I want to be able to rename the generated reports.
At the moment they are called something like this:
 `62e91fe28f676d9f760e63756d4ba1d2.html`
I want them to be named after the testcase creating them.
I have not seen anything about this in the Serenity Reference Manual nor elsewhere I could think of.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `serenity.compress.filenames` property in the `serenity.properties` or `serenity.conf` file to false. This will create a filename based on the test case path, test case name and test name. Note that if your test names/paths are very long it may cause issues with (some versions of?) Windows (that doesn't support file paths longer than 260 chars).

Comment: Does not seem to work for me. I tested it  with true and false and no change in created reports filename. My windows version does not support filenames longer than 260 chars so I put the output folder on the desktop and even then my reports where not named after the testcase.

Comment: Make sure your serenity.properties or serenity.conf file is accessible to the Serenity Maven plugin (e.g. by using serenity.properties in the root project directory).